# I can't draw on the canvas

Tags: html, css

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
```

Mouse over `<canvas>` does not draw.

```js
var TILE_WIDTH = 30;
var TILE_HEIGHT = 30;

document.getElementById("input").onchange = function() {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    // get loaded data and render thumbnail.
    document.getElementById("image").src = e.target.result;
  };
  // read the image file as a data URL.
  reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
};

// The first function call to create photomosaic 
function photomosaic(image) {

  // Dimensions of each tile
  var tileWidth = TILE_WIDTH;
  var tileHeight = TILE_HEIGHT;

  // creating the canvas for photomosaic
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.height = image.height;
  canvas.width = image.width;

  var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
  var pixels = imageData.data;

  // The Number of mosaic tiles
  var numTileRows = image.width / tileWidth;
  var numTileCols = image.height / tileHeight;

  // The canvas copy of image
  var imageCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var imageCanvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
  imageCanvas.height = image.height;
  imageCanvas.width = image.width;
  imageCanvasContext.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

  // A function for finding the average color
  function averageColor(row, column) {
    var blockSize = 1, // we can set how many pixels to skip

      data, width, height,
      i = -4,
      length,
      rgb = {
        r: 0,
        g: 0,
        b: 0
      },
      count = 0;

    try {
      data = imageCanvasContext.getImageData(column * TILE_WIDTH, row * TILE_HEIGHT, TILE_HEIGHT, TILE_WIDTH);
    } catch (e) {
      alert('Not happening this time!');
      return rgb;
    }

    length = data.data.length;

    while ((i += blockSize * 4) < length) {
      ++count;
      rgb.r += data.data[i];
      rgb.g += data.data[i + 1];
      rgb.b += data.data[i + 2];
    }

    // ~~ used to floor values
    rgb.r = ~~(rgb.r / count);
    rgb.g = ~~(rgb.g / count);
    rgb.b = ~~(rgb.b / count);

    return rgb;

  }

  // Loop through each tile
  for (var r = 0; r < numTileRows; r++) {
    for (var c = 0; c < numTileCols; c++) {
      // Set the pixel values for each tile
      var rgb = averageColor(r, c)
      var red = rgb.r;
      var green = rgb.g;
      var blue = rgb.b;

      // Loop through each tile pixel
      for (var tr = 0; tr < tileHeight; tr++) {
        for (var tc = 0; tc < tileWidth; tc++) {

          // Calculate the true position of the tile pixel
          var trueRow = (r * tileHeight) + tr;
          var trueCol = (c * tileWidth) + tc;

          // Calculate the position of the current pixel in the array
          var pos = (trueRow * (imageData.width * 4)) + (trueCol * 4);

          // Assign the colour to each pixel
          pixels[pos + 0] = red;
          pixels[pos + 1] = green;
          pixels[pos + 2] = blue;
          pixels[pos + 3] = 255;
        };
      };
    };
  };

  // Draw image data to the canvas
  context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
  return canvas;
}

function create() {
  var image = document.getElementById('image');
  var canvas = photomosaic(image);
  document.getElementById("output").appendChild(canvas);
};
```

```css
#output,
.container {
  text-align: center;
}

.inputDiv {
  margin: 20px 0px;
}

#image {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>test</title>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <img id="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" />

    <div class="inputDiv">
      <input id="input" type="file" accept="image/*">
      <button onclick="create()">create</button>
    </div>

    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
  </canvas>

    <div id='output'></div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

How do I create a circle when I touch the mouse? I'm sorry for the poor translation. This is the only place to ask. I'm also sorry that the code is very long. Not applicable to script ...

Comment: you put a bunch of code in the question. where exactly do you think the problem is? What part of the code is responsible for drawing on the canvas?

Comment: You need to add a mouse event handler to your code and use your context to draw a circle when the mouse event happens.